# how to build using expression for data conversion when alter column type

Tags: postgresql

I have a column `Status` with type `smallint`, which I want to convert it to `uuid`. The new value should be generated like this:

1. If the old value equals to `0` then take `uuid_nil()` as new value
2. Otherwise, take a random value from `uuid_generate_v1()`

*The convert logic described above could be changed to a simple one if it's not possible to achieve.*

I checked the [pg docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-altertable.html) here and I guess I should use a `USING` clause to do that but I am not sure where to start with this expression.

```
ALTER TABLE myschema."MyTable"
ALTER COLUMN "MyColumn" TYPE uuid
USING ?
```

Could anyone show an example or some instruction docs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no `uuid-ossp` module dependency:

```sql
ALTER TABLE myschema."MyTable"
ALTER COLUMN "MyColumn" TYPE uuid
using (
 case 
   when "MyColumn" = 0 then '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'::uuid
   else gen_random_uuid()
 end
);
```

This will generate UUID v4 and not v1.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like people find answer to their question right after they post it in StackOverflow.

A `CASE ... THEN ... ELSE ...` expression works for me.

```sql
ALTER TABLE myschema."MyTable"
ALTER COLUMN "MyColumn" TYPE uuid
USING CASE WHEN "MyColumn"=0 THEN uuid_nil() ELSE uuid_generate_v1() END
```

Although `uuid_generate_v1()` always generateds the same value but it can be fixed out of box later.